# Gatsby useStatciQuery react hook errors

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm a newer developer and just diving right into gatsby.  I have a working db and the graphql endpoint works fine in the sandbox page, but when I moved the query into a hook that is called by a component, I'm running into an error

> React Hook "useStaticQuery" is called in function "getCoinsByBuzz" that is neither a React function
> component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names
> must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

The code is very similar to the examples on Gatsby's docs.

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";

export const getCoinsByBuzz = () => {
    const { dataset } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query coinsByBuzz {
        coins {
            coinByBuzzChange {
            coinName
            timestamp
            symbol
            value
            buzzScore
            buzzScoreDelta6
            timestampDelta6  
            }
        }
    }`);
  
    return dataset.coinsByBuzz;
};
```

```
import * as React from "react"
// import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { getCoinsByBuzz } from "../hooks/getCoinsByBuzz"


ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);

export const LineChart = () => {
    const { dataset } = getCoinsByBuzz();
    console.log(dataset);
    return (
        <div style={{ width: '750px' }}>
          <p>{dataset}</p>
        </div> 
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code is very similar to the examples on Gatsby's docs.

I don't know anything specific about the docs, but from what I can see it seems like your `getCoinsByBuzz` function is intended to be used as a custom React hook. React hook names (***must***) start with a "use-" prefix.

[Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?** Please do. This
> convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
> automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
> couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
> it.

There's nothing intrinsically special about React hooks, they are plain Javascript functions with some [special usage rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) applied against them.

Suggested update:

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";

export const useGetCoinsByBuzz = () => {
  const { dataset } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query coinsByBuzz {
      coins {
        coinByBuzzChange {
          coinName
          timestamp
          symbol
          value
          buzzScore
          buzzScoreDelta6
          timestampDelta6  
        }
      }
    }`
  );

  return dataset.coinsByBuzz;
};
```

...

```
import { useGetCoinsByBuzz } from "../hooks/getCoinsByBuzz";

export const LineChart = () => {
  const { dataset } = useGetCoinsByBuzz();
  
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '750px' }}>
      <p>{dataset}</p>
    </div> 
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had issues because apparently rules are different for hooks in typescript and I'm using regular javascript.

Regardless I decided this component needs to be dynamic so I'm going to use axios to fetch data on page render